# Java debug and run yields different results

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

So, my friend and I have encountered a problem during development and can't seem to figure it out.

**A little background info**:

We have implemented a *Best First Search* along with a datatype *Node* enabling us to search through a tree of *Node*'s. Note that in our datatype we overwrite the *hashCode* function as a result of the more complex part of our implementation.

If a *Goal-Node* is found the searching stops and a solution is extracted using every *Node*'s parent to compile a list of the traversed path.

The program is more complex than just this, but I hope this description is sufficient enough for now :)

**The Issue**:

We have different inputs (*of the same standard*) to this search problem and whenever a search problem can't be solved, we debug our algorithm to find out how and why it behaves as it does.

One particular input however gives a weird response. The normal *build and run* does not work and throws an exception while searching, indicating to us that something is wrong, but when we try to debug it, the searching completes and gives us a correct solution from what we can gather.

As the debugging mode completes and works, we are having a hard time of actually debugging it as you might imagine :)

- From this behavior we speculate that our code somehow works differently in the debugging VM?
- What difference is there between the normal *run* and the *debug run*?
- How can the execution vary between the two?

**Normal Run**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.HashSet.<init>(HashSet.java:118)
at conflict.ClearPathConflict.solveConflict(ClearPathConflict.java:133)
at searchclient.Plan.getExpandedResolutions(Plan.java:233)
at searchclient.Plan.solve(Plan.java:94)
at search.SearchHTN.getExpandedNodes(SearchHTN.java:33)
at search.SearchHTN.search(SearchHTN.java:59)
at searchclient.SearchClient.run(SearchClient.java:127)
at Debug.main(Debug.java:12)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The `HashSet` is supposed to be a set containing the nodes of a path in the tree and we think that because a solution is not found, the `NullPointerException` is thrown.

**OBS**: The `NullPointerException` is not the important part in our system, the difference between executing in run and debug mode is.

**Debug Run**:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65492', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:65492', transport: 
'socket'
Found plan

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The `Found plan` output means that we have found a solution to a problem and a plan detailing the solution has been made. We have checked this in debugging mode and as far as we can see, the found plan is a valid solution.

**What have we tried?**

- We've tested the code on different machines.
- Different OS'.
- Ran it in IntelliJ and command line Java.
- Pulled a fresh version from our repo and recompiled it.

Same result every time, if we compile and run it normally the searching fails, but when we debug it, it actually completes and gives a correct solution to the problem.

We've also noted that the searching seems to continue for a longer period of time before it fails, than we it completes. That is, it explores a lot more nodes in the failing *run* than in the *debug run*.

We are at a loss here, so we hope that you guys can help us by asking, guessing or something else :)

Thanks in advance!

**TL;DR**:

Normal compile and running the java program yields a different result than when running it in debugging mode. Since the debugging mode yields the correct result, we are not able to find what went wrong in the normal mode.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). - please [add](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) the *complete* error message. and a
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Interesting, can you be more explicit about the exception ?

Comment: Ah yes, of course - Sorry about that. The problem has baffled me :D! I've edited and added the problem errror message :)

Comment: what does happen if you log every run of your application (debug and non-debug) and compare logs against each other?

Comment: The exception indicates that the collection you passed to `HashSet`’s constructor was already `null`. You may use the stack trace to retrace where the `null` argument did come from and under what circumstances it may be `null`. Having different outcome may be due to timing differences (usually indicates multi-threading related bugs) or due to the history of the JRE session, which may indicate that some of you code is relying on unspecified things, e.g. `HashMap`/`HashSet` iteration order.

Comment: The output log yields vastly different results. The strategy used to find the solution is very different in the two scenarios. The `NullPointerException` is not what worries me (in fact we can get around that). The problematic part is that when debugging, the solution is found in seconds and when running in production, the algorithm never completes.

Comment: @Holger good point. We do use a lot of `HashMap` and `HasSet`. However the debug result always yields the same result and the production as well. They're consistent, but different, indicating that there is no _randomness_ happening here. We do not have any multi-threading what so ever why this problem nags me.

Comment: It’s not so surprising that the results are reproducible. In each environment, the same code will be executed in each run, but it will be slightly different due to the fact that in one environment, the code of the debug agents will be executed during startup. Note that you can use profilers to connect to a JVM that has not been started in debug mode while it is already running. They allow to take heap dumps and thread stack trace snapshots. While not being as helpful as breakpoints and step-by-step debugging, it might still provide hints about what’s going on.

Comment: @Holger thank you - I will try with some heap and stack trace snapshots. FYI I just ran a test on a `HashSet` populating it with random values of a known seed and iterating the set afterwards. Debug and production execution still yields the same consistent result (same with `HashMap`).